# Regex - scrape only root domains from urllist on webpage

Tags: regex

I want regex code for only scraping .com domains without any subfolders or anything after the .com.

for example: 
on a webpage with a list of urls i want to scrape http://www.google.com and http://www.yahoo.com but not http://www.google.com/hello.html or http://www.yahoo.com/news/

Comment: Also, [8 Regular Expressions You Should Know](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know/)

Comment: From regex tag description: *Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using.*

Comment: Regular expressions aren't a magic wand that you wave at every programming task that involves strings.  This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice. For example, Perl has the [URI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/) module, and PHP has the [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.  Rather than writing code to interpret the URLs, use existing code that's already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`(https?:\/\/)?www.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[^/\s]*`